# I set up Firestore in my project. I created new collection named most. In this collection I created 10 documents. but my code is getting error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I set up Firestore in my project. I created new collection named most. In this collection I created 10 documents . but my code is getting error!

```
Future getMost() async {
      final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      QuerySnapshot snapshot =
          await firestore.collection('most').getDocuments();
      return snapshot.documents;
    }
```

getDocuments is getting an error ...is there any other way to do it

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Dharmaraj..this is the error - the method 'getDocumets' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'

Comment: Do you have proper permissions set up

Comment: @O-9- yes i have proper pemission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622922/the-method-getdocuments-isnt-defined-for-the-type-collectionreference). Try using `get()` as referred in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots)

Comment: `Future getMost() async {
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore.collection('most').get();
  return snapshot.docs;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, check if you have properly setup Firestore in your project:
   Checkout [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/26435435-firestore-tutorial-for-flutter-getting-started#toc-anchor-007) guide upto the installation part

2. After setting up Firestore properly in your project, Use the latest method, `get()` instead of `getDocuments()` on your collection reference:

```
Future getMost() async {
      final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      QuerySnapshot snapshot =
          await firestore.collection('most').get();
      return snapshot.docs;
    }
```